# Some folders are unreadable

Tags: permissions, files, filesystem

I use Ubuntu 18,After a power cut, some folders have disappeared, I tried to recover them but couldn't, then after few days, they are back but I can't access them.
If I open the folder it asks for password, but it doesn't open when i type it, showing "unreadable".

edit: screenshots of the problem.

[smart data of Disks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSblG.png)
[smart data of Disks 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oiBC.png)
[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5HDy.png)
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svEfX.png)
[screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z3yw.png)

Comment: Do you have those files in your lost+found directory ? Take a look at [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/282374/what-is-the-lostfound-folder-on-linux-and-macos/). It's stated that " there’s a slim chance you can do anything with the corrupted partial files. The fsck command put them there just in case"

Comment: And if you want to notify someone , please add @username in your comment , otherwise he/she might never get notified.

Comment: Edit your question and show me screenshot(s) of the `Disks` app **SMART Data & Tests** data.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi, there is some list of numbers and '#' before them

Comment: @heynnema, I've added the screenshots

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots... however, the SMART Data window is a scrollable region, and we need to scroll it and get a second screenshot so I can see all of the data. Do you know how to `fsck` your disk?

Comment: Lets first check your file system for errors. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, open a terminal window by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T, type `sudo fdisk -l`, identify the `/dev/XXXX` device name for your "Linux Filesystem", then type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX`, replacing `XXXX` with the number you found earlier. Repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors, then reboot and update your question with the results.

Comment: @heynnema, there were no errors, also, i have added the second screenshot for smart data

Comment: The SMART data looks fine. fsck was fine, yes? Do you have backups of your system/data?

Comment: @heynnema, fsck didn't catch any errors, and there is no backups of the data

Comment: Without backups, I really can't help you. Some file corruption must have occurred, but that's all we can say at this point. Sorry.

Comment: @heynnema okay, I appreciate your help, i will just be more careful with the data in the future.